# Invalid serving of static file with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, static, python-3.5, aiohttp

I have simple aiohttp one-page web app and want to serve static files with aiohttp itself

```
app.router.add_static('/static/', os.path.join(root_path, 'static'))
```

But when accessing resource from browser I have an error
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` because `index.js` file was served in some unexpected way.
[image]
[image]

Env:
`aiohttp==1.0.3`, `Python 3.5.2`, `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

[image: Some headers for browser response]

Was the file saved improperly or it's OS error or something wrong with aiohttp itself?

Comment: issue eliminating while I use `dos2unix` on that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason of the error was os `sendfile` that was caching/serving files in some wrong way.
`export AIOHTTP_NOSENDFILE=1` solved an issue. Link with more details [here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.UrlDispatcher.add_static).
Of course, for production environment use nginx to serve your static files.